# how do i get the username in cs-cart smarty block

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

I'm using the newest Cs-cart and I need to get the username inside a smarty block or any other smarty supported template. I couldn't find the answer in cs-cart knowledge base. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username is either inside `$user_info` or `$user_data`.

Just dump the var (in your smarty template) to see what's inside: `{$user_info|@var_dump}`.

`<li class="user-name">{$user_info.firstname} {$user_info.lastname}</li>`

or

`<li class="user-name">{$user_data.firstname} {$user_data.lastname}</li>`

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on the setting in the DB as to whether the customer uses the 'username' or 'email' for login.  Either one is available as above and 'email' is most common now (In fact, I don't even think usernname is an option anymore but would be inherited if site's been around since V1 or V2).

In checkout, the info is 
`$cart.user_data`
In order, the info is just part of the order_info like: 
`$order_info.email`

Rather than adding an anchor tag in your template to view variables, I find it's better to simply use an html comment and then to 'view source'.  I.e.

`<!-- $my_var|print_r:true -->`

But other method is fine too for short-term debug.